# Thumbnails grid wall as wall paper?

Tags: css, z-index, fixed

I want to make a wall of thumbnails to suit a screen resolution of 2560x1440px. I want the grid to sit behind my page acting as a background on the site.

However, when the page is scrolled the grid stays still. I have made some CSS and HTML and tested it in Firefox 4 and Chrome which seems to work fine. In IE8 it doesn't work, the page `div` doesn't overlap the grid wall but sits under it.

When testing CSS / HTML on IE use the proper format. Instead of just throwing the CSS and HTML on the page only.

Comment: why don't you make a big tile file and use it as a background? it will be much faster to load as well. on second thought.. just don't use a background, your site will be much more beautiful.

Comment: The images will be an active wall of php generated photos from members. Each a link to its own photo. The page over the topp is using a .png 40x40px allready. I need to overlap the page div over the grid div. Thats my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't have an HTML document. You just have some HTML tags that you are throwing at the browser, and the browser tries its best to use it, and does that surprisingly well.

As you don't have a `doctype` tag, IE renders the page in quirks mode, which basically means that it tries to emulate the oldest possible way of doing everything. As `position:fixed` is a recent addition, it's not supported in this mode.

A valid HTML document needs the `html`, `head`, `title` and `body` tags, and you need a `doctype` tag to keep the browser from rendering the page in quirks mode. So, the minimal HTML document that renders in standard compliant mode looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Your `style` tag goes inside the `head` tag, and the content goes inside the `body` tag.

There are different `doctype` tags that you can use, depending on which version of HTML you want to use, see [W3C's Recommended list of Doctype declarations](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html).

Comment: Thank you! :-). Valuable lesson learned for such a simple test. I guess I'm spoiled from using FF chrome too much, i was test in IE last. Maybe i should test in IE first.

Comment: @jonnypixel: Test in IE eary, but don't test in IE first, because it has some rendering bugs that other browsers doesn't have. If you develop for IE you will most likely be *using* these rendering bugs in your layout, and then you have to start over when you want it to work in other browsers.

Comment: thanks for that very wise feedback again. It makes good sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't merge your background image, then you need to use z-index. Give #grid a lower z-index than #wrap and you'll be sorted (as long as both elements are positioned, which they are at the minute).

```
#grid { position: fixed; z-index: -1; }
#wrap { position: relative; z-index: 1; }
```

Comment: Thank you sam, thats getting close to the solution i need. I applied your advice to the css but for some silly reason IE8 still dont like it.

Answer (score 0):

How about merging the thumbnails as one png/jpg file? Then you can:

```
body
{
    background: url('thumbnails.jpg');
}
```

Don't need to fiddle with z-index no more.

Comment: body tag css is good, but my grid div is generating thumbnails with php, each thumbnail is clickable. My page div needs to overlay it. The effect is to suit larger resolution screens where more of the members photos will be visible around the page as a grid wall.